# backgroundworker class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am learning backgroundworker class in WPF. The code below is in file MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.ComponentModel;

namespace FrontEnd
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker backGroundWorker;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backGroundWorker = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("backgroundWorker"));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            button1.IsEnabled = false;
            Flow pro = new Flow(20,10);
            backGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(pro);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Flow pro = (Flow)e.Argument;
           e.Result = pro.NaturalNumbers();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value= e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.Result == 1) MessageBox.Show("DONE");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is in file Flow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace FrontEnd
{
    class Flow
    {
        long i;
        //private int x,y;
        public int X
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Flow(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
        public int NaturalNumbers()
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                long iteration = i * 100 / 9999;
                if ((i % iteration == 0) &&
                (backgroundWorker != null) && backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress)
                {
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(iteration);
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error : The name 'backgroundWorker' does not exist in the current
>   context

How can I make progress bar working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that works:

```
public partial class BackgroundWorkerPage : Page
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public BackgroundWorkerPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerOnProgressChanged;
    }

    private void WorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs progressChangedEventArgs)
    {
        progressBar.Value = progressChangedEventArgs.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            _worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Height="23" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
</Grid>
```

And you need to change your code a bit

```
private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    var flow = new Flow(_worker);
    flow.NaturalNumbers();
}

internal class Flow
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public Flow(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Flow(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        _worker = worker;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int NaturalNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
        {
            int iteration = i*100/9999;

            // your if(...) fails with divide by zero exception

            _worker.ReportProgress(iteration);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,what if iteration happens inside a method of another class called '**Image**'?(assume method is '**SendImage**') and I want to report progress, Number of bytes left to be sent.

Comment: The method doing the work either needs a reference to the background worker in order to call ReportProgress, or it can raise an event or call a delegate so that the class that owns the worker can call ReportProgress.  Or you can send the progress straight to the WPF control/window (using event/delegate), but you will need to use Dispatcher.Invoke to marshal the call onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

Whenever we try to do some long running operation on the UI without freezing it, we need to run it in a separate thread.In this article we will look into the BackgroundWorker class , as one of the various solutions to this problem with a simple example. BackgroundWorker executes an operation on a separate thread and provide a notification to UI Thread whenever necessary.
Straight To Experiment

Let us create a UI as under

[image]

The objective is that,when we will click on the "Populate" button, at the same time we should be able to write something in the "Textbox".

Now let us look into the code which is without BackgroundWorker

```
public partial class WithOutBackgroundThread : Form
{  
    List<Employee> lstEmp;

    public WithOutBackgroundThread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lstEmp = new List<Employee>();
    }

    private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        GetEmployeeRecords();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lstEmp;
        lblStatus.Text = "Work Completed";
    }

    //Prepare the data
    private void GetEmployeeRecords()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            // Simulate a pause
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lstEmp.Add(new Employee { EmpId = i, EmpName = "Name" + i });
        }
    }
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward.In the "GetEmployeeRecords()" method, we are preparing the data.We have introduce the "Thread.Sleep(1000)" to make a delay. And in the "Populate" button click event, we are populating the Gird.

But if we execute this code, the UI will become unresponsive and henceforth, we cannot perform any task on the "Textbox" which is our objective.

Henceforth let us change our code to the below

```
public partial class WithBackgroundThread : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker workerThread;
    List<Employee> lstEmp;

    public WithBackgroundThread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lstEmp = new List<Employee>();
        workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThread_DoWork);
        workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted);

    }

    private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        workerThread.RunWorkerAsync(); 
    }

    private void workerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        GetEmployeeRecords();
    }

    private void workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Work Completed";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lstEmp;
    }

    //Prepare the data
    private void GetEmployeeRecords()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            // Simulate a pause
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lstEmp.Add(new Employee { EmpId = i, EmpName = "Name" + i });
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of new things.We will explore one by one.

First, we need to declare BackgroundWorker Thread

```
BackgroundWorker workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Next,we need to subscribe to the events

```
workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThread_DoWork);
workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

As a third step, we need to implement the two methods

```
private void workerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // run all background tasks here
   GetEmployeeRecords();
}

private void workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //update ui once worker complete its work
  lblStatus.Text = "Work Completed";
  dataGridView1.DataSource = lstEmp;
}
```

The "DoWork" event is raised when we call the "RunWorkerAsync" method. This is where we start the operation that performs the potentially time-consuming work.The "RunWorkerCompleted" event is fired when the background operation has completed, has been canceled, or has raised an exception

As a last step, invoke the "RunWorkerAsync" from the "Populate" button click event.

```
private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    workerThread.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}
```

The "RunWorkerAsync" starts execution of a background operation.

Now if we run our application we will be able to populate the grid as well as write something on the "Textbox".

[image]

Thanks